# Data showing up in the frontend above where it's called

Tags: php

I have a simple class to work with viewing the people who are blacklisted in my web application. Here is the index.php

```
require_once "../model/ViewBlacklist.php";
// Handling a navigation to the webpage
try {
    $viewBlacklist = new ViewBlacklist("view-blacklists.php", "View Blacklists", $navForUser);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Here is the `ViewBlacklist` class:

```
class ViewBlacklist {

    function __construct(string $page, string $pageTitle, string $navbar) {

        if (empty($_POST) && empty($_GET) && empty(file_get_contents("php://input"))) {
            $_SESSION["CSRFTOKEN"] = hash("sha512", random_bytes(64));
            $csrfToken = $_SESSION["CSRFTOKEN"];
            $pageTitle = $pageTitle;
            $navForUser = $navbar;
            $usernameBlacklist = "<table id='usernameBlacklistTable'>";
            $usernameBlacklist .= "<thead><tr><th>Username</th><th>Time Blocked</th><th>When time will expire</th><th>Remove Blacklist?</th></tr></thead>";
            $usernameBlacklist .= "<tbody>";
            $usernameBlacklist .= $this->getBlacklistedUsernames();
            $usernameBlacklist .= "</tbody>";
            $usernameBlacklist .= "</table>";
            $ipAddressBlacklist = "<table id='ipAddressBlacklistTable'>";
            $ipAddressBlacklist .= "<thead><th>Ip Address</th><th>Time Blocked</th><th>When time will expire</th><th>Remove Blacklist?</th></thead>";
            $ipAddressBlacklist .= "<tbody>";
            $ipAddressBlacklist .= $this->getBlacklistedIps();
            $ipAddressBlacklist .= "</tbody>";
            $ipAddressBlacklist .= "</table>";
            include_once $page;
            exit;
        }

    }

    private function getBlacklistedUsernames() : string {
        $blacklistedUsernames = "";
        $initDB = new DatabaseConfig();
        $db = $initDB->start_db();
        $sql = "SELECT username, added, allowed FROM blacklisted_users";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $stmt->closeCursor();
        if (!empty($data)) {
            var_dump($data);
        } else {
            return "<tr><p class='empty-table-return'>There are no blacklisted usernames</p></tr>";
        }
    }

    private function getBlacklistedIps() : string {
        $blacklistedUsernames = "";
        $initDB = new DatabaseConfig();
        $db = $initDB->start_db();
        $sql = "SELECT ip_add, added, allowed FROM blacklisted_ips";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $stmt->closeCursor();
        if (!empty($data)) {
            var_dump($data);
        } else {
            return "<tr><p class='empty-table-return'>There are no blacklisted IP addresses</p></tr>";
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is, where I'm calling `$this->getBlacklistedUsernames();` or `$this->getBlacklistedIps()` the return from that data (which is currently in the else, because nothing lives in my blacklist tables right now) is going *above* my tables, so the words `There are no blacklisted usernames` appear above the entire `<table>` element contained in the variable `$usernameBlacklist` and the same for the ip addresses. Here is how it is called in the frontend:

```
<?php include_once "../header.php"; include_once "../nav.php"; ?>

<?php echo $usernameBlacklist; echo $ipAddressBlacklist; ?>

<?php include_once "../footer.php";
```

What is making my return from my `get...()` functions appear above the variable they're concatenated into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is, it was actually an HTML validation problem. It turns out that you can't have an element be a direct descendent of a `<tr>` element that isn't a `<td>` element. So the reason it was a problem was because my `<p>` element had no `<td>` parent surrounding it, so the html validation failure forced the `<p>` up to the top.